# Nested JSON Objects in Kotlin with Volley

Tags: json, android-studio, kotlin, android-volley, nested-object

I am very new to this as you can probably tell, but i'm trying to parse a JSON url with Volley using Kotlin in Android Studio. The url contains nested Objects, not nested Arrays.

I can display everything inside "questionnaire", but I only want to display "typeOfQuestion". How do i do that?

MainActivity.kt:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    questionTV = findViewById(R.id.idTVQuestion)
    answerTV = findViewById(R.id.idTVAnswer)
    typeTV = findViewById(R.id.idTVType)

    val queue: RequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(applicationContext)

    val request = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, { response ->
        loadingPB.setVisibility(View.GONE)

        try {
                val question: String = response.getString("question")
                val answer: String = response.getString("answer")
                val typeOfQuestion: String = response.getString("typeOfQuestion")

            questionTV.text = question
            answerTV.text = answer
            typeTV.text = typeOfQuestion

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

    }, { error ->
        Log.e("TAG", "RESPONSE IS $error")
        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Fail to get response", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show()
    })
    queue.add(request)
}
}
```

Heres the JSON:

```
{
  "questionnaire": {
      "question": "Where do you live?",
      "answer": "In the mountains",
      "typeOfQuestion": "Informative
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have object inside another json object.If you need to access field from child object you need to get child jsonObject and then get fields from object.

```
var questionnaire = response.getJSONObject("questionnaire")
```

You need to get fields from questionnaire object.Like.

```
val question: String = questionnaire.getString("question")
val answer: String = questionnaire.getString("answer")
val typeOfQuestion: String = questionnaire.getString("typeOfQuestion")
```

Comment: But what do i do with the json in "json.getJSONObject" because I haven't declared it or mentioned it in previous code.

Comment: I said that. You need to add that line. 
var questionnaire = json.getJSONObject("questionnaire")
And then the three links.
You cannot get nested object directly from root object.JSON parser cannot does not understand if you try to access nested  object from root object directy

Comment: Thank you so much for commenting, but I get "unresolved reference: json" with the first line "var questionnaire = json.getJSONObject("questionnaire")"

Comment: Updated it . It is response.getJSONObject instead of json.getJSONObject.

Comment: IT WORKED! Thank you so much! You have no idea how long that took me hahah